# symfony4 UserProviderInterface implementation with api calls authentification

Tags: symfony, security

I'm developing a symfony4 webapp. Users accounts are stored on a DB accessible via an API.

I want to implement this [UserProviderInterface](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/User/UserProviderInterface.php) as it is [advised by the symfony4 documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html) to use the symfony4 security module features.

If I understand, implementing this interface requires the API (or service, or db...) to return data (for example hashed password / salt) that will be checked by symfony security.

Is there a way to use the symfony security module without getting such data from the user provider ?

For example to send username and password entered in login form by the user to the api, which will check if it is correct and return a bool ?

Comment: Do you want to **proxy** username/password to another API and grant access depending on the remote API's response ... instead of validating username/password with providers and security encoders provided by symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own **Guard Authenticator** to perform the authentication checks manually.

There is a good example implementation described in the documentation chapter:

[How to Create a Custom Authentication System with Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html)

An example configuration would look like this:

```
security:
  firewalls:
    firewall_api:
      pattern: '^/(.*)+$'
      host:    '^api\.mypage\.com$'
      stateless: true
      anonymous: false
      guard:
        # list of authenticators to try
        authenticators:
          - 'My\Bridge\Symfony\Security\Authenticator\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator'
          - 'My\Bridge\Symfony\Security\Authenticator\Guard\FacebookAuthenticator'
        # This authenticator's start() method is called
        entry_point: 'My\Bridge\Symfony\Security\Authenticator\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't really get how to use guard with a form login to check if api accepts credentials

Comment: What do you mean by *API accepts credentials*? What API - the one you're building? What shall happen after authentication - set a session-cookie, return an authentication-token for re-use? Do you want to authenticate by POSTing a simple form with username/password or authenticate via a JSON payload? Or do you just want to know how to validate a username/password combination against a provider inside a controller/service? :)

Comment: it is a custom API that returns a json user authentication-token for re-use if credentials are accepted. I would like to post to it at login and then re-use it to allow the user to browse the site and make other requests to the api to display data.

Comment: If I understand I need 1) to implement a user provider that posts to the api to get a token and then 2) to use guard to validate the user's token when he browses the application ? What I still don't get is how to post username/password to the api if I can only access username in https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/master/User/UserProviderInterface.php

Comment: You sent a link to a **UserProvider**. A user provider is responsible for fetching  a `UserInterface` by given username. Not more not less. I already pointed you towards a custom **Guard Authenticator** in my answer. You can inspect the current request for username **and** password inside the `getCredentials(Request $request)` method easily.

Comment: Sorry, the "// make a call to your webservice here" in the doc confused me. I think I got it now. Thanks